# FK Constraint error

Tags: mysql, replication, foreign-key

I am in the process of setting up a replication between my production server and a secondary. The two machines connect to each other perfectly and I think I set things right. I dumped my prod that I injected into the secondary, but at the start, I got the following error:

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 192.168.0.100
                  Master_User: replica
                  Master_Port: 35120
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000029
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 576277494
               Relay_Log_File: replica-relay-bin.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 6581
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000029
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 1452
                   Last_Error: Could not execute Write_rows event on table trio.HistoPt; Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`trio`.`HistoPt`, CONSTRAINT `FK_HISTOPT_HISTO` FOREIGN KEY (`histoIdProduct`, `histoRank`) REFERENCES `Histo` (`idProduct`, `rank`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTIO), Error_code: 1452; handler error HA_ERR_NO_REFERENCED_ROW; the event's master log mysql-bin.000029, end_log_pos 576055596
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 576054646
              Relay_Log_Space: 229638
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 1452
               Last_SQL_Error: Could not execute Write_rows event on table trio.HistoPt; Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`trio`.`HistoPt`, CONSTRAINT `FK_HISTOPNT_HISTO` FOREIGN KEY (`histoIdProduct`, `histoRank`) REFERENCES `Histo` (`idProduct`, `rank`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTIO), Error_code: 1452; handler error HA_ERR_NO_REFERENCED_ROW; the event's master log mysql-bin.000029, end_log_pos 576055596
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID: b2921fc8-ec55-11ea-a854-d05099d6f4f6
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State:
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 210226 13:14:17
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I don't understand why I have this error on the secondary, I should have it also on the primary, right? how can i fix this, i'm not sure which key is causing concern.
Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Examine `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` for more details on the foreign key error. Based on the error, it sounds like your replica does not have the same data as its source.

Comment: The data are those of the dumps of this night. So there is a lag, but I started the slave from the position indicated by a show master status. But maybe the lag is too big.

That said, I also stopped my primary database, redid a dump, injected into the slave and restarted the two servers Same problem.

I checked the variables of the two servers, they are identical. I really do not understand.

Comment: You're capturing the log coordinates from the dump, right? Not trying to run SHOW MASTER STATUS on the source and hope that it's "close enough?"

Comment: heu .. I'm reading the general and error logs on my slave, and I check the position on the master. Maybe, I'm wrong ...

Comment: You need the _exact_ binlog coordinates at the time you created the dump file. This is done with [mysqldump --master-info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_master-data).

Comment: Carefully compare `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on the Primary and Replica (for each relevant table).